# Which SSD drives support TRIM

Tags: ssd, trim

Which [Solid State Drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) currently support the [`TRIM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) command?  Do not include drives which use a specialised tool such as `wiper.exe`; I am asking about the `TRIM` command.  Please list one per answer, with a citation and firmware version if possible.

Comment: If you're asking for one per answer, then: community wiki please.

Comment: Done!  Now community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GSkill forum](http://gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?t=2496)

The new GSkill Falcon series support TRIM under Windows Seven.

And the first generation of Falcon support TRIM too through a firmware update (before that, it was only through [wiper.exe utility](http://gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?t=733)).
Problem: the firmware update will erase all your data...

[image: picture of the new firmware upgrade program]

---

Edit: December 2009

- [TRIM Now Available for OCZ Summit Series SSDs](http://www.ocztechnology.com/aboutocz/news/155)
- [Corsair: The TRIM available on the Samsung MLC SSD](http://www.techfuels.com/latest-hardware-news/27288-trim-available-samsung-mlc-ssd.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3667), Intel X25-M G2 drives support `TRIM`, but the G1 drive does not.

Comment: Note that there have been reports that Intel's firmware update has been bricking drives.  I am not sure if the newest firmware update resolves this issue.

Comment: The bricking issue was resolved in a firmware update.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3667), Indilinx Barefoot supports `TRIM`.  This includes SuperTalent UltraDrive, firmware version 1819, and OCZ Vertex, firmware 1.40.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 4, 2009, the Corsair Extreme series of drives **do not** support TRIM.  In this forum thread, an official rep says, ["I am sorry as we do not have any updates at this time and as far as I know the new firmware mentioned above had some issues and was or will be pulled until further notice. But we are still working on it."](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=82629).